# Shade specific part of background based on number

Tags: python, plotly

I need to create a double graph. Basically, one graph has a "normal" plot - it's the price of, let's say, Giraffes over time. The other plot is based on the amount of Giraffes I owned at the time.

The other plot needs to expressed by shading the background of the plot accordingly.

[image]
How would I go about creating the shaded graph-thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can Plotly's [`shape`](https://plot.ly/python/shapes/#highlighting-time-series-regions-with-rectangle-shapes) in the layout settings.

[image]

```
import plotly
import time
import random
import datetime

#create some random input data
N = 100

starttime = time.time()
x = [datetime.date.fromtimestamp(starttime - 60*60*24*N).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')]
y = [10]
for i in range(N):
    x.append(datetime.date.fromtimestamp(starttime - 60*60*24*N + i*60*60*24).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    y.append(abs(y[-1] + random.randint(-7, 5 + int(N/25))))

trace = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(
    x = x,
    y = y,
    mode='line',
)

layout = dict(shapes = list())
#highlight the minimum in red
layout['shapes'].append(
    {
        'type': 'rect',
        'xref': 'x',
        'yref': 'paper',
        'x0': trace.x[trace.y.index(min(trace.y)) - 5],
        'y0': 0,
        'x1': trace.x[trace.y.index(min(trace.y)) + 5],
        'y1': max(trace.y),
        'fillcolor': '#ff0000',
        'opacity': 0.2,
        'line': {
            'width': 0,
        }
    }
)

#highlight the maximum in green
layout['shapes'].append(
    {
        'type': 'rect',
        'xref': 'x',
        'yref': 'paper',
        'x0': trace.x[trace.y.index(max(trace.y)) - 5],
        'y0': 0,
        'x1': trace.x[(trace.y.index(max(trace.y)) + 5) - ((trace.y.index(max(trace.y)) + 6) % len(trace.y))],
        'y1': max(trace.y),
        'fillcolor': '#00ff00',
        'opacity': 0.2,
        'line': {
            'width': 0,
        }
    }
)

fig = dict(data=[trace], layout=layout)
plotly.plotly.sign_in('user', 'token')
plot_url = plotly.plotly.plot(fig)
```